# É possível editar dados da ListBox?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Ao duplo click na linha a ser editada da ListBox, abre-se o UserForm com os dados da linha selecionada.
Não consigo fazer com que as alterações sejam modificadas no ListBox e na Planilha.
Código ao iniciar o UserForm:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Item As Integer

 For Item = 0 To UserForm.ListBox1.ListCount - 1

       If UserForm.ListBox1.Selected(Item) = True Then

        TextBox1 = UserForm.ListBox1.List(Item, 0)
        TextBox2 = UserForm.ListBox1.List(Item, 1)
        TextBox3 = UserForm.ListBox1.List(Item, 2)
        TextBox4 = UserForm.ListBox1.List(Item, 3)
        TextBox5 = UserForm.ListBox1.List(Item, 4)
        TextBox6 = UserForm.ListBox1.List(Item, 5)
        TextBox7 = UserForm.ListBox1.List(Item, 6)
        TextBox8 = UserForm.ListBox1.List(Item, 7)
        TextBox9 = UserForm.ListBox1.List(Item, 8)

       End If

 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Olá. Não está claro o problema. Você gostaria de recolocar na lista os valores digitados pelo usuário nos TextBoxes, é isso? Outra coisa: por que raios vc faz um laço for se pega os itens um a um?

Comment: Estou tentando editar dados pelo LixtBox, então no duplo click abre o UserForm e os textbox são carregados com os valores da linha selecionada da Lixtbox. não estou conseguindo que esses valores fiquem alterados após edição. Quanto o laço achei que resolveria, foi a última tentativa que fiz. Sou leigo no assunto.

Comment: Entendi. Realmente não está nada claro na pergunta. Que tal adicionar algumas capturas de tela do seu projeto executando? Outra coisa: você menciona "planilha", mas pelo jeito só quer saber como atualizar o valor de uma linha numa ListBox (e não na planilha! e por isso obteve uma resposta que não te ajudou).

Comment: Eu respondi com base *no que eu entendi* do que você descreveu em comentário. Mas vou manter meu voto pra fechar até você editar a pergunta e deixar lá mais claro, ok?

Comment: Luiz bom dia! Você informou outro item que não tinha prestado atenção que é salvar a alteração na planilha também. Porque quando fazer uma pesquisa futuramente já estará arrumado. Mas salvando na planilha fica muito difícil pra mim ajustar o código acredito.

Comment: Cara, sinto muito, mas eu não entendi o que você comentou. "Salvando na planilha fica muito difícil pra mim (sic) ajustar o código" -> isso era um comentário ou uma pergunta?

Comment: Foi um comentário. Não estou conseguindo falta o "New Editar". Não consigo anexar o print da tela!

Comment: Se vc tem outra dúvida, deveria abrir uma nova pergunta. Leia [ask]. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Sim, é possível. Basta alterar o valor da propriedade `List` no índice do objeto selecionado. Eis um exemplo de código com dois UserForms (um chamado "Teste", que exibe a ListBox, e outro chamado "Editar" que exibe o conteúdo do item atualmente selecionado da lista e permite editá-lo):

### UserForm "Teste"

Imagem da tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
(A ListBox se chama "ListBox"; o UserForm "Teste" é criado uma única vez e reutilizado)

Código:

```
Dim oEditForm As Editar

Private Sub ListBox_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    Dim sName As String

    sName = Me.ListBox.List(Me.ListBox.ListIndex)
    oEditForm.EditName.Text = sName
    oEditForm.Show
    If oEditForm.Tag = True Then
        sName = oEditForm.EditName.Text
        Me.ListBox.List(Me.ListBox.ListIndex) = sName
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Set oEditForm = New Editar

    Me.ListBox.AddItem "Tyrion Lannister"
    Me.ListBox.AddItem "Jaime Lannister"
    Me.ListBox.AddItem "Cersei Lannister"
    Me.ListBox.AddItem "Daenerys Targaryen"
    Me.ListBox.AddItem "Jon Snow"
    Me.ListBox.AddItem "Petyr Baelish"
    Me.ListBox.AddItem "Jorah Mormont"

End Sub
```

### UserForm "Editar"

Imagem da tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
(os botões se chamam "Ok" e "Cancel", e o TextBox se chama "EditName")

Código:

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    Me.Tag = False
    Hide
End Sub

Private Sub Ok_Click()
    Me.Tag = True
    Hide
End Sub
```

### Resultado

Imagem da tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Explicação do código:

1. Primeiro você precisa capturar o evento apropriado de duplo click, chamado `*_DblClick`.
2. Então, obtenha o texto do item atualmente selecionado na lista a partir de `ListBox.List` passando o índice dele que está em `ListBox.ListIndex`.
3. Coloque esse valor no seu outro formulário de edição e permita ao usuário editá-lo. Quando ele clicar em Ok, vá para o passo seguinte.
4. Tendo o usuário editado o valor, atualize o conteúdo *do mesmo item atualmente selecionado* na lista (isto é, usando `ListBox.List` passando o índice dele que está em `ListBox.ListIndex`).